# Working with Integer values for NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, enums, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to create some settings for my application. One of which is a sort setting which can be 0,1,2. At present I have an enum to handle this:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSInteger, SearchSort) {
    SearchSortDefaultBestMatched = 0,
    SearchSortDistance = 1,
    SearchSortHighestRated = 2
};
```

When a value is selected from a picker I update the `[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] setInteger:`

However, when a user first runs the app there is no default set. What I am finding is that if check the `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:...];` this returns 0. Which would be incorrect. Is this the correct process to store this value/check if the defaults has a value? Ideally I would want nil instead of 0 as 0 would potentially be an option.

Unless the proposed solution is to of course store the values as 1,2,3 and translate back and forth.

Comment: I would follow the suggestion from your last sentence, start the enum at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: This is what `NSUserDefaults registerDefaults:` is for.

Comment: Maddy and I both gave the same answer. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSUserDefaults has a method `registerDefaults` for this very purpose. you give it a dictionary of "default default" key/value pairs. Those become the initial values that you get when you ask for a given key that has not been set.

I always add my initial default values in the `+initialize` class method for my app delegate. That method gets called before the system alloc/inits the app delegate, so it gets called before any of your app's custom code (Aside from the code in main) gets called.

### EDIT:

As @AdamEberbach suggests in his answer, you can also use `objectForKey:` instead of `integerForKey`. That will return nil if no value is stored, or an `NSNumber` (who's value may be zero) if a value has been stored.

Comment: Thanks for the record I did both approaches. Set the default value with `registerDefaults` then for the values being stored I ensured they were 1,2,3 instead of 0,1,2 and translated them back down when they were needed.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `objectForKey:` instead, if you get a valid object then you can cast to `NSNumber` and get the `integerValue:` - else you get a `nil`.